# bottom navigation fragment api call frequently when click the bottom item

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, android-studio-3.0

I have an android app with bottom navigation and fragment java. In fragment the API is calling through retrofit. bt when we click the item by double tab change the every fragment the api is calling frequently. Bt it will disturb users as well occurs server load. i want that when app open then only api will called not called every time when we click the item by double clicked.

i want that when app open then only API will called not called every time when we click the item by double clicked.

Comment: Just call the API in `onViewCreated` method of the Fragment

Comment: Can you help me by Teamvier?

Comment: I cannot help like that, just post your code and we may help you based on your case.